# How to redirect logs from secondary threads in Azure Functions using Python

Tags: python, multithreading, azure, logging, azure-functions

I am using Azure functions to run a Python script that launches multiple threads (for performance reasons). Everything is working as expected, except for the fact that only the info logs from the main() thread appear on the Azure Functions log.
All the logs that I am using in the "secondary" threads that I start in main() do not appear in the Azure Functions logs.

Is there a way to ensure that the logs from the secondary threads show on the Azure Functions log?

The modules that I am using are "logging" and "threading".

I am using Python 3.6; I have already tried to lower the logging level in the secondary threads, but this did not help unfortunately.
The various secondary thread functions are in different modules.

My function has a structure similar to the following pseudo-code:

```py
def main()->None:
  logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
  logging.info("Starting the process...")
  thread1 = threading.Thread(target=foo,args=("one arg",))
  thread2 = threading.Thread(target=foo,args=("another arg",))
  thread3 = threading.Thread(target=foo,args=("yet another arg",))
  thread1.start()
  thread2.start()
  thread3.start()
  logging.info("All threads started successfully!")
  return

# in another module

def foo(st:str)->None:
  logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
  logging.info(f"Starting thread for arg {st}")
```

The current Azure log output is:

```
INFO: Starting the process...
INFO: "All threads started successfully!"
```

I would like it to be something like:

```
INFO: Starting the process...
INFO: Starting thread for arg one arg
INFO: Starting thread for arg another arg
INFO: Starting thread for arg yet another arg
INFO: All threads started successfully!
```

(of course the order of the secondary threads could be anything)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I did something like that. I think it creates multiple threads and there is one main thread. As main thread end, it tells azure function to stop. That's why you did not get logs.

Comment: Yes - I came to the conclusion that using 'traditional' multi-threading libraries in Azure Functions is probably a moot point, because it is just best to use the features that  are provided in Functions, such as queues.

Comment: Did this get resolved?

Comment: I would rather use Durable Azure Functions. That way it will be much easier to parallelize

Comment: Im not sure this is of any help, but would this be easier using the multiprocessing library in Python as opposed to threading?

Answer (score 4):

Azure functions Python worker framework sets `AsyncLoggingHandler` as a handler to the root logger. From this handler to its destination it seems logs are filtered along the path by an `invocation_id`.

An `invocation_id` is set if the framework starts threads itself, as it does for the `main` sync function. On the other hand if we start threads ourselves from the `main` function, we must set the `invocation_id` in the started thread for the logs to reach its destination.

This `azure_functions_worker.dispatcher.get_current_invocation_id` function checks if the current thread has a running event loop. If no running loop is found, it just checks `azure_functions_worker.dispatcher._invocation_id_local`, which is thread local storage, for an attribute named `v` for the value of `invocation_id`.

Because the threads we start doesn't have a running event loop, we have to get `invocation_id` from the `context` and set it on `azure_functions_worker.dispatcher._invocation_id_local.v` in every thread we start.
The `invocation_id` is made available by the framework in `context` parameter of `main` function.

Tested it on Ubuntu 18.04,  azure-functions-core-tools-4 and Python 3.8.

```
import sys
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import threading

# import thread local storage
from azure_functions_worker.dispatcher import (
    _invocation_id_local as tls,
)


def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info("Starting the process...")
    thread1 = threading.Thread(
        target=foo,
        args=(
            context,
            "one arg",
        ),
    )
    thread2 = threading.Thread(
        target=foo,
        args=(
            context,
            "another arg",
        ),
    )
    thread3 = threading.Thread(
        target=foo,
        args=(
            context,
            "yet another arg",
        ),
    )
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread3.start()
    logging.info("All threads started successfully!")

    name = req.params.get("name")
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get("name")

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
        )
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
            status_code=200,
        )


# in another module


def foo(context, st: str) -> None:
    # invocation_id_local = sys.modules[
    #     "azure_functions_worker.dispatcher"
    # ]._invocation_id_local
    # invocation_id_local.v = context.invocation_id

    tls.v = context.invocation_id

    logging.info(f"Starting thread for arg {st}")
```

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/blob/81b84102dc14b7d209ad7e00be68f25c37987c1e/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py

Comment: Fixed the issue, threads now log.

Comment: for anyone looking at this solution, the argument name was changed from `v` to `invocation_id`

Answer (score 0):

This must be something in your Azure setup: in a non-Azure setup, it works as expected. You should add `join()` calls for your threads. And `basicConfig()` should be called only once, from a main entry point.

Are your threads I/O bound? Due to the GIL, having multiple compute-bound threads doesn't give your code any performance advantages. It might be better to structure your code around `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` or `multiprocessing`.

[Here is a Repl](https://replit.com/join/zatspljpkp-vsajip) which shows a slightly modified version of your code working as expected.

Comment: Your example doesn’t look like an Azure Function, so probably you missed that important aspect of the question. It’s about Azure Functions ;-) The whole point of spawning off a thread (in my case) is that it is supposed to do something *after* the HTTP request has been answered with an HTTP response. A `join()` is therefore not possible. `basicConfig()` isn’t called explicitly; Azure sets that up. 
Yes, the spawned thread is supposed to read from the network. Just one thread, so no GIL involved. I have doubts the thread actually runs, though; as the logging doesn’t happen, I cannot be sure.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're right, I missed that.

Comment: If you want to be sure, juste replace log mechanism with print(file=open('myfile') unstead of logging in your thread fonction for now (for troubleshoot sakes).

Comment: I would also try to set daemon=False flag in your child creation (quoting doc: The entire Python program exits when no alive non-daemon threads are left.) 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I suspect azure to run your main function in a daemon thread.

Quoting https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html: The entire Python program exits when no alive non-daemon threads are left.

When not setting daemon in the Thread constructor, it reuses the value of the father thread.
You can check this is your issue by printing `thread1.daemon` before starting your childs threads.

Anyway, I can reproduce the issue on my pc writing (without any Azure, just plain python3):

```py
def main():
  logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
  logging.info("Starting the process...")
  thread1 = threading.Thread(target=foo,args=("one arg",),daemon=True)
  thread2 = threading.Thread(target=foo,args=("another arg",),daemon=True)
  thread3 = threading.Thread(target=foo,args=("yet another arg",),daemon=True)
  thread1.start()
  thread2.start()
  thread3.start()
  logging.info("All threads started successfully!")
  return

def foo(st):
  for i in range(2000): # Giving a bit a of time for race condition to happen
    print ('tamere', file = open('/dev/null','w'))
  logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
  logging.info(f"Starting thread for arg {st}")

main()
```

If I force daemon to False / leave it undefined, it work. Thus I guess your issue is that azure start your main function in a daemon thread, and since you don't override daemon flag to False, the whole process exit instantly.

PD: I know nothing about Azure, there is a possibility that you are indeed trying to do something the wrong way and there is another interface to do exactly what you want but in the way Azure expect you to. So this answer is potentially just an explanation of what happens rather than real guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Azure functions is an async environment.

If you define an `async def`, it'll be run with `asyncio`.

Otherwise it'll be run with `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`.

It's better to define your functions `async`.

Threading works. You don't need to start threads manually. Thread pool executes your blocking code. You have to make it work for you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#python_threadpool_thread_count

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to install azure-functions-worker that was used in Nizam's answer, due to some issue on Linux with grpcio dependencies being unable to install. Azure also warns not to use azure-functions-worker in your functions so you don't accidentally modify something critical. Instead, you should do:

```
import azure.functions as func
import threading
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(context, 'Thread1 used.'))
    t1.start()
    
    return func.HttpResponse("Ok", status_code=200)
    
def thread_function(context: func.Context, message: str):
    context.thread_local_storage.invocation_id = context.invocation_id
    for _ in range(10):
        logging.info(message)
```

I found this [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/1358#issuecomment-1858604425).