# Azure function background thread runs without showing log message

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, azure-functions

[Environment]

Win10, Python3.7.3

[Description]

I have a function that needs to return early and do some background jobs. However, all log messages in these jobs do not show up in the console (also application insights)

Here is the sample code:

```py
import logging
import time
from threading import Thread

import azure.functions as func


def helper(arg1, arg2):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    for ind in range(3):
        logger.info(f'{arg1}, {arg2}, {ind}')
        time.sleep(1)


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logger.info('creating threads ...')
    tasks = []
    arg_list = [(1, 11), (2, 22), (3, 33)]
    for (arg1, arg2) in arg_list :
        task = Thread(target=helper, args=[arg1, arg2])
        # args:list, kwargs:dict
        task.start()
        tasks.append(task)

    logger.info('leaving the function ...')
    return func.HttpResponse("received", status_code=200)
```

[Expected result]

All the messages produced by `helper()` show in console (also application insights)

It should show something like this:

```sh
1 11 0
2 22 0
3 33 0
leaving the function
3 33 1
1 11 1
2 22 1
3 33 2
2 22 2
1 11 2
```

[Actual result]

```sh
[2021-07-07T05:38:24.638Z] Executed 'Functions.logging_test' (Succeeded, Id=bb0f4035-7c96-4f79-a7d3-0ba5e7971d05, Duration=28ms)
[2021-07-07T05:45:03.861Z] Executing 'Functions.logging_test' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=61898196-c1ff-42c6-b668-0c48b2f182c0)
[2021-07-07T05:45:03.881Z] creating threads ...
[2021-07-07T05:45:14.168Z] leaving the function ...
[2021-07-07T05:45:14.173Z] Executed 'Functions.logging_test' (Succeeded, Id=61898196-c1ff-42c6-b668-0c48b2f182c0, Duration=10316ms)
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe /d /c func host start" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

And here is the setting of my function

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Warning",
      "Function":"Debug"
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: change the `default logLevel to `Information` instead of warning. Also, turn off the sampling of applicationInsights.

Comment: Hi @user1672994 . I follow your suggestion, change "logLevel.default=Information" and "applicationInsights.isEnable=false" in `host.json`. Then test it on local (using vscode). The problem still exists. However, if I replace `logger.info(f'{arg1}, {arg2}, {ind}')` with `print()`, the log messages shows up (but only part of the whole execution).
Correct me if I misunderstand your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Got fixed at https://stackoverflow.com/a/72583775/4522780

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to properly set the invocation_id of the thread from/within the function context, like this:

```
import azure.functions as func
import threading
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(context, 'Thread1 used.'))
    t1.start()
    
    return func.HttpResponse("Ok", status_code=200)
    
def thread_function(context: func.Context, message: str):
    context.thread_local_storage.invocation_id = context.invocation_id
    for _ in range(10):
        logging.info(message)
```

Found this [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/1358#issuecomment-1858604425).